# How to make header fixed even when keyboard is up on mobile web?

Tags: html, css

I am making a web screen for mobile. I fixed the header as `position:fixed`,
When the keyboard is raised, the header rises above the screen. How can I fix the header even when the keyboard is raised?

[image]

Comment: Can you share some of your actual html and css. It might be more helpful to have this information

Comment: Please read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After 
that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide 
a [repro] for debugging details.

Comment: I'm having the same problem and I found this link that explains how to fix it: https://www.codemzy.com/blog/sticky-fixed-header-ios-keyboard-fix

Comment: @GustavoSantamaría the solution in the link is not work for android, did you found the solution that work for android and ios?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I am fighting this problem now.

Answer (score 0):

I've been facing this same problem, you can use `window.visualViewport` to get only the Viewport Height (minus Keyboard Height)

Comment: You should share a code example of how exactly that's implemented.

Answer (score -1):

Here you go.

Just need to use `position: fixed` with a header.

```css
.main {
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
}

main {
  margin-top: 50px;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
  color: #fff;
}

footer {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background: yellow;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">

  <header>This is header</header>
  <main>This is main section</main>
  <footer>This is footer</footer>


</div>
```

Comment: The user has stated in their question that `position: fixed` wasn't working for them

Comment: We already have this, but are getting the exact behavior from the user's mock-up screenshots